Python Multiprocessing of an object method
I have a python code that operates on measurements of devices. In one section, I have to apply a matching network to the measurement. I am handling everything related to rf measurement with Scikit Rf module and I am creating a circuit with the stuff I need, and then extract the network from the circuit with the .network attribute, and substitute it to the network attribute of my object.
This operation is pretty slow and I would like to speed it up by doing multiple matching in parallel. Note that this operation is done element by element and nothing is fed back to a main loop or anything, the only thing that gets updated is the .network attribute of my object (which is an rf.Network).
I have tried the following (suggested by chatGPT):
def process_element(element, matching_network):
    return element.apply_matching(matching_network)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool: 
    pool.starmap(process_element, [(element, matching_network) for element in list_measurements])

I know that the method apply_matching() works because I have tested it extensively, but the multiprocessing does not. When I plot measurements, I see them unmatched, so the replacement between the original response and the matched response did not take place.
Edit: I am not a very proficient coder, and it is the first time I have used this multiprocessing, so please be aware of that. In the meantime, I am trying to documenting myself on the topic, but since I need this code in my work, I need to get it done.
Anyway, to break it down to the most simple form, I need to apply a method (apply_matching) to an object (element) with a set of parameters (matching_network). Matching_network does not change during the execution of the code.
The method does some operations and then modifies one attribute of the object with a new value.
Second Edit:
the code I have now is the following:
def apply_matching(self, matching_network)

  network = self.network
   # operations on network using matching network

   self.network = result

[..]
for element in list_measurement:
   element.apply_matching(matching_network)

This is what I need to speed up, with multiprocessing.

Well, what does the function do? Does it modify element or matching_network? If it does, those changes won't be propagated back up to the multiprocessing parent process.

Sorry, I did not specify. It uses matching network, which is common for every element, to modify element.

Please provide a minimal example of what the problem is.  There are too many unknown elements in your question.

I have added some context

Right, so any internal modifications to element won't be propagated up to the parent process. You'll have to e.g. change things so you have a function that returns the changes to apply to that element, and then apply them in the parent process.

I can absolutely return the value of the attribute that needs to be changed for a particular, but then I am lost in what to do


I can absolutely return the value of the attribute that needs to be changed for a particular, but then I am lost in what to do

You'd process the changes in the loop that's executed in the parent process – a self-contained example:
import dataclasses
import multiprocessing


def get_element_value_using_matching_network(element, matching_network):
    # This would be your current `apply_matching` logic, but in a way that it returns
    # the new values instead of applying them directly.
    # I'm using a dict as the "guts" of the matching network for simplicity.
    return {"bar": matching_network[element.id]}


def process_element(task):
    element, matching_network = task  # need to unpack by hand so we can use imap
    element.foo = 123  # this won't propagate (just here for show)
    return get_element_value_using_matching_network(element, matching_network)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Element:
    id: int
    foo: int = 0
    bar: int = 0


def main():
    list_measurements = [
        Element(1),
        Element(2),
        Element(3),
    ]
    matching_network = {2: "two", 1: "yksi", 3: "drei"}

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        for element, changes in zip(
            list_measurements,
            pool.imap(
                process_element,
                [(element, matching_network) for element in list_measurements],
            ),
        ):
            for key, value in changes.items():
                setattr(element, key, value)

    print(list_measurements)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This prints out:
[Element(id=1, foo=0, bar='yksi'), Element(id=2, foo=0, bar='two'), Element(id=3, foo=0, bar='drei')]

so you can tell bars got mapped, but foos didn't (as you noticed).

thank you for the time you spent on this! However, there are some things that are a little bit unclear to me, probably because I failed to properly explain my issue. Matching network needs to be passed to the method, but the result of the method is not known a priori. I need to compute the method result considering things existing inside the attribute. Let's say that each elements contains a Foo attribute, and I need change the Foo attribute by the int passed in matching network

Sure. That's essentially what's happening here – instead of an element.apply_matching that internally applies the change to element.foo, you'd have a function that just returns the new value(s) so they can be applied to the object in the parent process. I expanded the example to make it a bit clearer.

what it is not clear for me is this: you return a dictionary with "bar" being the attribute of each object that needs to be updated. But the value to which I need to update "bar" is not contained in maching network, but it is the result of the method. It is not clear for me how this applies to my case. I will add a new edit to the original post to show what inputs and output my original function has

Did you see my edit? You can think of matching_network to just be some opaque data – it just so happens to be a dict that contains the result, but it could be anything else too.

can you check the last edit on the original post, and in case, modify your piece with the names I have used? matching_network --> opaque parameter used by the method, result --> original attribute that gets modified and stored back to each element, element --> object in the list_measurements

If the network also needs to change based on the result, then this is not really easily parallelizable – you'd need to broadcast changes to the network to all of the other workers too.

would it be easier if I convert the method to a function that has network and matching_network as input and gives back network? Then I set the attribute outside from the function

That still won't help with parallelization, if all the workers are expected to have a shared view of the network as it changes.

I have solved my issue. What I ended up doing is extract the attribute 'network' from the list of objects.
I have then passed this to a function that does the operations I need and returns the network, modified by 'matching_network'. This is the function that gets parallelized.
Then, the outcome of this parallel functions is a list in which I have all the modified networks, and I reapply all this networks by replacing the attribute network to each element. Not super pretty, in my opinion, but it works!
